# CSS issues Internet Explorer 11 online, offline working fine

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some trouble with a website in Internet Explorer 11. All other browsers work fine, both with local and online files. Now the strange thing is, in Internet Explorer 11, my local files view perfectly fine. However, when i put the files on the network drive (intranet-page) the layout is completely messed up. Does anyone have an idea how this is happening?

With kind regards.

Comment: Did you get any errors in console? Provide more information...

Comment: With so little info, it is hard to guess. Have you used to dev tools to see if there’s _any_ errors in console or network panel? Maybe different security zones have an impact too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found with IE, if you are using an intranet page ie. aliased in dns as intranet, then it treats it with compatibility mode and treats it as if it were ie7.

go to the settings and compatibility options and turn off compatibility mode for intranet sites,

you can tell if its doing so, go to inspect element (f12) and top right of the bar will show the compatibility mode of it, ie 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,edge

Comment: It looks indeed like it has something to do with compatibility mode. With inspect element i see it is in ie7 mode. I have added 

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"> 

to force IE10 mode and now it works. Is there a better way to disable compatibility mode?

Comment: yea, as i said, click the cog in the top right, go to compatibility options, then there is a tick box saying to run intranet pages in compatibility mode, 

If you're on a domain and need this to happen on all pc's then you need to do a registry entry in gpmc, 

in server 2012r2 theres a recent update that includes it as a default ie option in gpmc though.